# All versus all comparisons in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am relatively new to PySpark.

I have 2M train instances and 4M test instances. Each instance is represented by an id and a feature vector. I have a self-defined function that computes the similarity between two pair of instances.

As an output, I want for every test instance, a ranked order of the train instances. It is a very regular problem but the number of instances are the challenge.

Since, I have to do a all-vs-all comparison, I used the `cartesian` product function in PySpark as follows:

```
 train_testpairs = trainRDD.cartesian(testRDD)
 train_testpairs_simscores = train_testpairs.map(myscore)
```

In, train_testpairs_simscores, I have tuples of the following type:

```
 (train_id,test_id,score)
```

But, now I want a sorted order of the train instances for each test instance such as:

```
 test_id1,[train_id432, train_id832,.....]
```

I understand, for each test_id, this will have a 2M size list. Therefore, it would also be ok to have n% of this list..say the top 1000 train instances closest to the test id.

How can I achieve this?

I was trying to group by the testID and then sort within each list but the `groupBy` itself is too time consuming.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

facing a very similar problem, i ended up computing the similarity score 'manually' instead of using `cartesian()`:

```
def f(train_instance):
   return train_instance,sorted(myscore(train_instance,test_instance) for test_instance in TEST_INSTANCES)

trainRDD.map(f)
```

this way you avoid expanding the cartesian product of 2m*4m items and then regrouping them